# How do you implement a timed limit order?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have this pipeline in mind:

```
1. condition to enter a trade becomes TRUE
2. opens a limit order at a pre-calculated price
3. wait 3 bar closes (or 3 hours, for example. variable.)
4. if the order has not filled, cancel the order
```

Particularly, how can steps 3-4 be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel the pending limit order using the built-in strategy.cancel() function, check if the condition for long was true 3 bars ago and cancel the order, in case it was filled - it will be not affected.

The script below will trigger a condition to go long using a mouse click on the chart, with a given limitValue for limit order and cancel the order in case it will not be executed during next 3 bars:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true)

itime = input.time(0, confirm = true)

limitValue = math.min(close[1], low[2])

longCondition = time == itime

if longCondition
    strategy.entry("MyLong", strategy.long, limit = limitValue)
    label.new(bar_index, limitValue, 'Entry Order')

strategy.cancel("MyLong", nz(longCondition[3]))
```

Comment: Thanks! Just having some strange issues: adapating/adding this condition makes it so that my script is no longer generating ANY trades. I also tried this script on its own with nothing else, it also seems to generate no trades at all. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There is a confirm=true argument that should show a pop-up when you add the script to the chart, to enter a trade you should select a date on the chart using mouse. You can also hardcore the date by removing the confirm= argument.

Comment: Thanks, I've understood that part now. Removed the "confirm=true" argument, and specified a random recent date on a random ticker, but it looks like a typical market entry on close. In trading panel, it says long entry opened at 1801. Candle close (at the specified itime) = 1801. Close[1] = 1801.7. Low[2] = 1800.3. The very next candle went below Low[2]. Shouldn't the limit order be filled at 1800.3?

Comment: Oh, I think I know what's going on... Close[1] and Low[2] are calculated backwards from the current candle, not backwards from the itime candle. So this should work well in forward-testing, is there a relatively simple way to also implement this for back-testing?

Comment: Solved, by only porting the nz(longCondition[3]) part of the code to an existing strategy rather than using the itime template, the trades and backtests are being generated normally.

Comment: Sorry, yeap, the time entry was just an example, the cancelling part is in the last line )